# Variable in Bash Script that keeps it value from the last time running

Tags: linux, bash, variables

Can I create a Bash script with persistent variable-values?

For example, I initialize a variable with 0 when the script runs for the first time (during a specific time limit), and the variable increases automatically with every time the script is running.

Comment: key/value database write in bash script; https://github.com/damphat/kv-bash :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't, but you can use a file to do it

```
#!/bin/bash

valuefile="/tmp/value.dat"

# if we don't have a file, start at zero
if [ ! -f "$valuefile" ]; then
    value=0

# otherwise read the value from the file
else
    value=$(cat "$valuefile")
fi

# increment the value
value=$((value + 1))

# show it to the user
echo "value: ${value}"

# and save it for next time
echo "${value}" > "$valuefile"
```

Comment: Note that `expr` is an artifact from the 1970s. All shells compliant with the POSIX sh standard support `value=$((value + 1))`, whereas `expr` is not part of the standard and not guaranteed to be present in new, POSIX-compliant shells and operating systems.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy which operating system doesn't have expr (or at least busybox)? please summate 15904148959 + 1 and see why we should prefer expr before aritmethic expansion

Comment: @alecxs, you're moving the goalpoasts -- with built-in POSIX shell math, it's *a shell feature* and you don't need your operating system to provide any binaries external to the shell. You don't spend the time loading the external binary to execute that feature; you don't need an extra `fork()` for a command substitution to capture its output; you don't need to worry about whether implementations vary (and they _do_ vary; I've seen some supporting regex features, for example, whereas others don't). And how `expr` handles overflow is OS-by-OS dependent...

Comment: ...so even if it does the right thing somewhere you happen to be testing, that's absolutely no guarantee it does the right thing anywhere else. If folks want math with arbitrarily large numbers, POSIX **does** standardize tools that are guaranteed to be suited to the purpose on any compliant platform -- `bc` is a prime example -- but `expr` is not such a tool; it is not standardized, it is not guaranteed to be present even on POSIX-compliant systems; if it *is* present it isn't guaranteed to have any particular behavior.

Comment: On any 64-bit platform where the shell is bash, I recommend `value=$((value + 1))`, which will correctly handle any partition size in bytes that your OS can handle (contrary to your prior assertion, `echo $((15904148959 + 1))` works fine). If you're on a 32-bit system that _can't_ handle that, then `value=$(bc <<<"$value + 1")`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so your solution isn't working on basically every armv7 android device https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q4qq.png

Comment: Talk to the people who decided to compile that specific copy of `busybox` to provide `expr` (which isn't standard-mandated or even referenced), but not `bc` (which is both). Note that `busybox` is fully configurable -- it *can* provide `bc`, and it *can* fail to provide `expr`. But the one that fails to provide `expr` is still standards-compliant; the one that fails to provide `bc` isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you have to save the state in a file somewhere. The trick is to put it somewhere the user will be able to write to.

```
yourscriptvar=0

if [ -e "$HOME/.yourscriptvar" ] ; then
    yourscriptvar=$(cat "$HOME/.yourscriptvar")
fi

# do something in your script

#save it output the file
echo $yourscriptvar > "$HOME/.yourscriptvar"
```

Comment: Here's a bash-ism: `yourscriptvar=$(< "$HOME/.yourscriptvar")`. Documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem a few days ago and I've written my own tool to do the work because there is not other way to do something similar.

**[gvar](https://github.com/arturoherrero/gvar)** is a pure Bash key-value store where each user has a different collection of data. The records are stored in the user's home directory.

Here it is the most interesting functions from the source code:

```
get_variable() {
  cat $FILE | grep -w $1 | cut -d'=' -f2
}

set_variable() {
  echo $1=$2 >> $FILE
}

remove_variable() {
  sed -i.bak "/^$1=/d" $FILE
}
```

Comment: Huh. You would think that for such a 'library' it would be optimized for speed. For example, `cat` is unnecessary if you use `grep` since `grep` can already take a file as an argument. Besides, I wonder how this would work well in parallel execution if it doesn't use `flock` or something.

Comment: @Yeti you are completely right, gvar is just a toy that resolved my problem but I haven't gone forward. I thought similar things that you pointed out. Thanks.