# In POSIX shell, how to increment a variable each run?

Tags: shell, sh, posix, increment

I want my script to know how many times it has been run. The script executes completely each time, and the number should be incremented before it exits. Each time I run the script, the number is the next increment.

Here's a basic example:

```
#!/bin/sh

num=1
increment=$((num+1))
echo $num

# do something with ${increment} to update this script's ${num} value
```

1st time, output is 1. It increments itself.

2nd time, output is 2.

3rd time, output is 3.

etc.

I intend to run the script as part of a build process, but it may not be a regular occurrence, so the script has to keep track of the incremented value in `num` so that I can reference it as needed.

I need to stay compliant with POSIX shell, and I want to avoid storing the `num` value in an external file. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Please explain better what you mean (no comments, [edit] your question with the clarifications), ideally providing a minimal, reproducible example. Do you want to leave the script running and then see how many times `num` was incremented? Or do you want to count how many times the script was executed? There is no "opening" a script, unless you mean to edit the script.

Comment: POSIX doesn't provide tools needed for file locking. If you want to do this in a way that guarantees that you'll get a new and distinct number per run *even if runs overlap*, you'll need non-POSIX tools (like `flock`, if on a GNU system).

Comment: @Quasímodo Hey, thanks for the push to clarify. Hopefully, this is a bit better. :)

Comment: BTW, this is very closely related to [variable in bash script that keeps its value from the last time running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904980/variable-in-bash-script-that-keeps-it-value-from-the-last-time-running). You'll note that the accepted answer is written for `sh`, even though the question specifies bash.

Comment: ...indeed, going through the answers there, I'm convinced that they address your problem (as much as one can without going into file locking).

Comment: There _are_ other folks who asked how to create self-modifying scripts, but that's in general a horrible idea -- such a script can easily be corrupted or deleted if you lose power at the wrong time. Much safer to only modify a data file that's loaded at runtime -- then the script itself isn't being changed on-disk and is less likely to be corrupted. Also better from a security practice perspective: Code that can modify itself is code that necessarily has enough permissions that an attacker who can perform code injection against it can modify how it behaves in the future.

Comment: Yes, it looks like what I need. (Being new to sh, it's been a challenge for me to separate sh and bash solutions in my searches.) However, I had hoped to avoid storing the incremented value externally in the event that users unknowingly delete it and lose the ongoing count. Is there any other way? Also, I'm unsure what you mean by file locking. I've not encountered this yet.

Comment: Idea - what if I just create a new copy of the entire script every time it's run with an updated value? And then delete the old one? It sounds ridiculous, but it's interesting.

Comment: It's not ridiculous -- that's how `sed -i` *works*. But the caveats (about security, potential data corruption, etc) still apply. (The data corruption modes are different, and depend on details of your filesystem and how it orders between data and metadata sync points, but they still exist). Self-modifying code also makes it hard to use change-control measures like deploying updates with packages, or validating checksums of on-disk content. (Think about it: Every time you want to deploy a new copy of your script, you'll need to make sure the variables get copied out of the old one).

Comment: As someone who's been doing this professionally for a lot of years, trust me: It's fewer problems in the long run if you keep your data out-of-band from your code and accept the need to manage the associated storage.

Comment: Mmm, good to know. It sounds like I just need to find a nice location to store that extra bit of data. Thanks for your insight. I really appreciate the help. :)