# Bash Script: Storing A Variable After Increment

Tags: linux, bash, audio, wget

I am putting together a script to download a pair of audio files each week from a website. The audio files have a naming convention that changes by one number each week (1001.mp3, 1002.mp3, etc.)

Here's what I've written:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i episode
episode=1800

wget --user username --password password https://website.com/mp3/$episode-1.mp3   
wget --user listener --password ripple02 https://website.com/mp3/$episode-2.mp3

let "episode=episode+1"
echo $episode
```

My hope is to start with the current episode number (1800), run the script, and then have the variable increased by one number and saved.

I've learned that this script as-written will not work, since I can't permanently update a variable inside of a bash script. Is there another way to do this? I was thinking of creating another file that stores a variable, that can be imported into my script, and then after it's used it will be increased by 1 and export that new value back to the file it was imported from. Is that possible, or is there another way to tackle this?

Comment: (select your code with your mouse, and then click on the `{}` in the edit menu to have clean `code/data/output/errMsgs` formatting. Good luck.)

Comment: if you need to catch up from 1800 to 1850?. you can do `episode=1800; while (( episode >= 1850 )) ; do wget ... ; wget ... ; ((episode++)) ; done`. Good idea to use a file, find a safe place to save it: `safeDir=/path/to/safePlace; newEpisode=$(<$safeDir/episode.dat) ; ((newEpisode++)) ; wget .... ; wget ... ; printf "%s" newEpisode >$safeDir/episode.dat` ... Just a rough idea. Save your good data/scripts someplace before experimenting. Good luck.

Comment: I hope we're not fighting each other on correct formatting (-;? I think there was a syncronization problem. Having individual lines of code in non-monospaced type face is generally considered hard to read. If you really want it that way, then feel free to edit again and revert to previous version. Good luck.

Comment: your `let var=var+1` syntax does work, but is "old-fashioned" (-;. Using `(( math statements ))` is the modern and much more powerful version. All `c` lang math operators are supported inside `(( ))` (almost all?) . Also, numeric variables inside of `(( ... ))` don't required leading `$` s. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and info, @shellter! I'm new to this, so all of this is helpful. It was suggested the answer to my question may be in another post, and it was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9904980/variable-in-bash-script-that-keeps-it-value-from-the-last-time-running

Comment: yes, the other post looks good. Cheers!